# Удаление одинаковых записей из сформированного запроса MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, фильтрация, запрос-в-запросе

Есть ***MySQL*** запрос:

```
SELECT pesp.position, name, pesp.id_plan 
FROM pp_stages pps 
LEFT JOIN pp_ex_stage_position pesp ON pesp.id_stage = pps.id 
ORDER BY id_plan <> 2, IF(position IS NULL,1,0), position
```

Он возвращает отсортированную таблицу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть необходимость убрать строки, которые повторяются. При том, нужно сохранить порядок и убирать последующие повторения.

Должно получиться так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как дополнить запрос, чтобы он мог выполнить данную операцию?

Пробовал так, но запрос сбивает порядок и удаляет не последующие повторения, а первые

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT pesp.position, name, pesp.id_plan 
      FROM pp_stages pps 
      LEFT JOIN pp_ex_stage_position pesp ON pesp.id_stage = pps.id 
      ORDER BY id_plan <> 2, IF(position IS NULL,1,0), position
     ) tbl
GROUP BY tbl.name
```

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При ORDER BY с JOIN последовательность в группе сложно предсказать. Зависит от индексов. При добавлении GROUP BY конкретная выбираемая из группы запись тоже сложно предсказуема. Используйте подзапросы лучше.

Comment: *Есть необходимость убрать строки, которые повторяются.* В показанном наборе НЕТ записей-дубликатов.

Comment: В следующий раз, когда задаете вопрос по SQL _всегда_ приводите исходные таблицы вместе с данными и желательно с `create table`, причем в виде текста. Мне пришлось потратить 20 минут что бы подготовить таблицы и заполнить их с картинки, при том что на решение ушло 3 минуты на первое, и 5 на второе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не привели структуры таблиц и исходные данные, будем предполагать что в таблице `pp_ex_stage_position` есть собственный id и что поле name находится в таблице `pp_stages`. Тогда запрос может выглядеть например так:

```
SELECT pesp.position, name, pesp.id_plan 
  FROM (
   SELECT pps.id, pps.name,
          ( select pesp.id from pp_ex_stage_position pesp
             where pesp.id_stage = pps.id 
             ORDER BY id_plan <> 2, IF(position IS NULL,1,0), position
             limit 1
          ) pos_id
     from pp_stages pps 
 ) A
 LEFT JOIN pp_ex_stage_position pesp ON pesp.id = A.pos_id 
ORDER BY id_plan <> 2, IF(position IS NULL,1,0), position
```

Или с использованием переменных, за один проход по таблицам, так:

```
select position, name, id_plan
  from (
   SELECT pesp.position, name, pesp.id_plan,
          @seen:=find_in_set(pps.id, @stages) seen,
          @stages:=if(@seen=0,concat(@stages,',',pps.id),@stages)
     FROM (select @stages:='') init
     CROSS JOIN pp_stages pps 
     LEFT JOIN pp_ex_stage_position pesp ON pesp.id_stage = pps.id 
    ORDER BY id_plan <> 2, IF(position IS NULL,1,0), position
  ) A
 where seen=0
```

Так же обращаю ваше внимание, что в случае если в таблице `pp_ex_stage_position` нет подходящей записи, то ваше условие `IF(position IS NULL,1,0)` в `order by` ничего не даст, NULL все равно окажутся в самом начале из за первого условия в сортировке.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Первый запрос работает на ура. Второй немного ошибается и Этапу 1 отдаёт id_plan = 1, а не 2.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev Хм. это странно. видать у вас оптимизатор как то совсем с другой стороны заходит. у меня на тесте оба дали один результат.